# ANDROID StringEntity fail inside eclipse

Tags: android

Sorry about this simple(?) question but I'm a newbie on java and android.

First I have this import section.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList; 

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;  
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.entity.*;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;

import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
```

Then I have this code.

```
            String s = new String();
            // Handle successful scan

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

            s += "enter=<eanrequest><ean>";
            s += contents;
            s += "</ean></eanrequest>";             

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);   
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("enter", s));

            ean.setText(s);

            HttpEntity se = new StringEntity(s);  //When I hold the mouse over this I get "Unhandled exception type UnsupportedEncodingException".
```

What am I doing wrong?

/Erik

Comment: Do you mean after the imports you just have the code you posted, without any class!? (anyway, the imports part is not relevant at all for a queston, you can always just go to Source-Organize Imports, and Eclipse will take care of them for you)

Comment: I didn't know this about eclipse thanks.

Comment: So, if you also have a class/activity beside the code you posted, from the message you get, I think it just want you to wrap that line in a try/catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
try{
    HttpEntity se = new StringEntity(s);
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

The StringEntity constructor can throw an exception that you have to handle. You can either wrap it in a try/catch block or declare that your method can throw an exception:

```
public void myMethod() throws Exception{
    //...
    HttpEntity se = new StringEntity(s);
    //...
}
```